# Retrieve XML result with ActionScript

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

That's my XML results :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<data>
    <row>
        <used>1</used>
    </row>
</data>
```

And I'm trying to retrieve the value of used tag like this :

```
private function onResult(param1:ResultEvent) : void
{
    var result:Object = param1.result.data.row[0];
    Alert.show(result.used);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work as expected...

Thanks !

Comment: What are you using to load the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <row>
       <used TITLE="your trace should show --> image1">image1.jpg</used>
       <used TITLE="your trace should show --> image2">image2.jpg</used>
       <used TITLE="your trace should show --> image3">image3.jpg</used>
</row>
</data>
```

actionscript3:

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("your_xml.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML.row.used[0].@TITLE); //this how to get the first value from your xml used[0]
}
```